# How to push WebApi path parameter into class that is request body, possible or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have tried to simplify the routing of my app. I tried to find way to changing this:

```
[Route("api/campaign/{campaignId}/launch")]
public HttpResponseMessage LaunchCampaign(long campaignId, CampaignLaunchRequest request)
{

    //do job
}
```

to something like this:

```
[Route("api/campaign/{request.Id}/launch")]
public HttpResponseMessage LaunchCampaign(CampaignLaunchRequest request)
{
    //do job
}
```

Can I somehow push the path variable into request body that is some class?

```
[Route("api/campaign/{request.Id}/launch")]
```

The "request" is the class `CampaignLaunchRequest` and `id` is field/property of this class

Is it even possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you must create MvcRouteHandler for this route and add your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar use case and was able to accomplish this by using a custom model binder "ModelBinder" attribute class.

For Example in your case:

```
[Route("api/campaign/{campaignId}/launch")]
public HttpResponseMessage LaunchCampaign([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))]
CampaignLaunchRequest request)
{

    //do job
}
```

To create a ModelBinder, you can check [this page](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) but basically you will be parsing the request and creating your own "CampaignLaunchRequest" object within "MyCustomModelBinder" which will run each time your method is called